Cursor keeps reset from `pointer` to `default` upon changing `document.title` on MacOS Firefox & Safari
I recently created a webpage, where there is a counter and a button.
The counter will +1 when the button is clicked, and the page title will also change according to the counter number.
I have a CSS that setting all buttons to have pointer as cursor on hovering, which working great:
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

However, when I change the page title accordingly:
function changeTitle() {
  document.title = count;
}

The cursor change from pointer to default, until it leave the button and re-enter it.

Let's organize a bit:
On MacOS Firefox & Safari, when I:
Click a button -> Increment Counter -> Change document.title
The cursor change from pointer to default

Sample Code:


var count = 0;

const counter = document.getElementById("counter");
const btn = document.getElementById("plus-one");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count++;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  document.title = `Now is ${count}`;
})
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#plus-one {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 8rem;
}
<html>

<head>
  <title>0</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="counter">0</div>
  <button type="button" id="plus-one">+1</button>
</body>

</html>




Only on MacOS Firefox and Safari
It is good on MacOS Chrome, Windows Chrome and Windows Firefox.
What's going on here?

This is an aside to the question, but .textContent is a much better alternative to .innerHTML, since it doesn't invoke the parser and introduce security vulnerabilities.

@Nanigashi Oh I see! Actually I am writing in VueJS, but found that vanilla JS got this problem as well and created a quick sample haha. Anyway thanks for the reminder!

To keep the pointer, you can remove the :hover. In fact, when you want to set mouse cursor as a pointer in button, you don't need to do it when hover event. You can simple do it without :hover.
button {
    cursor: pointer;
}


Yep, I was writing like this as well, but anyway not the reason. I am quite sure this is OS + browser problem, but just to check out if anyone has an explanation and solution
